Clarification for the application of topological data analysis to detect stock price crashes
I want to detect the stock price crashes using topological data analysis. For example I have taken an excel file named ‘tesla’ with columns date,open,high,low,close and volume. I want to work with the time series of the Close column. Now first I apply takens embedding theorem , then apply the slinging window. Then use rips complex to detect holes.
I have used some research papers on tda for gaining this information, but unable to understand why the things are implemented as it is provided in my above statements.
Thing which I fail to understand is that :

if I take the time series of Close column and apply takens embedding theorem then what do I get? What is the significance of this new thing?

After time delay series is formed we apply sliding window to it . Why?

After this we are trying to find the holes formed in the sliding window diagram. Now how can detecting the holes help in understanding the stock price crashes of the close values?


My main problem is how can tda help in finding the stock price crash. A practical example of this experiment if provided (assuming it to be for explaining purpose and not really done)
will help me clarify my doubts.
